# How to link a script file to an html file using nodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am serving up some html using nodeJS, but I want to be able to call functions that are in a javascript file, which I am trying to link. However, I am getting the error message `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8888/index.js"`. I'm not sure what that won't link properly, and need a way to link my file `index.js`. What I was trying to do was load the file into the head, as follows:

```
http = require('http'),

http.createServer(function(req, res) {

var body = '<html>'+
    '<head>'+
    '<script src="index.js"></script>'+
    '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; '+
    'charset=UTF-8" />'+
    '</head>'+
    '<body>'+
    '</body>'+
    '</html>';
response.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
response.write(body);
response.end();
}

}).listen(8888);
```

How can I load this javascript file, `index.js`, so that all of the functions contained in `index.js` will be available on the client side?

Comment: No matter what request comes in to your server you are serving this HTML content, you would need to detect that the file being requested is index.js and serve different content for that request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a new `index.html` page rather than hard coding it - include the script files in it and serve the `index.html`.

```
        var http = require('http');
        var fs = require('fs');

    http.createServer(function(req, res) {        
      if(req.url == '/index.html') {
        var file = __dirname + '/index.html';  //this index.html contains script tag
        var stat = fs.statSync(file);
        res.writeHead(200, {
          'Content-Type': 'text/javascript',
          'Content-Length': stat.size
        }); 
        var readStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
        readStream.pipe(res);
      // Send default page
      }
    }).listen(8888);
```

Answer (score 1):

The request for `index.js` is getting the same response as `/`.

A simple solution that only handles this one case would be:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  // Send index.js
  if(req.url == '/index.js') {
    var file = __dirname + '/index.js';
    var stat = fs.statSync(file);
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/javascript',
      'Content-Length': stat.size
    }); 
    var readStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
    readStream.pipe(res);
  // Send default page
  } else {
    var body = '<html>'+
        '<head>'+
        '<script src="index.js"></script>'+
        '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; '+
        'charset=UTF-8" />'+
        '</head>'+
        '<body>'+
        '</body>'+
        '</html>';
    res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
    res.write(body);
    res.end();
  }
}).listen(8888);
```

Comment: Thanks for your thought on this. This doesn't exactly do what I am aiming to do, however. What I am trying to do is simply like html page to a javascript file, keeping the existing html in place. This either serves up the one html file or a blank page, which has the index.js linked

Comment: @maudulus I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The first part of the if statement doesn't send whatever html is inside of the `body`, though it does send up the functions from `index.js`; the second part of the if statement sends up `body`, but doesn't send up  `index.js`

Comment: That's because in the `else` part it serves up the html. The script tag in the html makes a request for the external script `index.js`. When the server gets a request for `index.js` it serves up your `index.js` file (from the `if` part). So you'll be getting two requests. Are you saying you want to write every line of `index.js` between the `<script>` and `</script>` tags in the html?

Comment: The script tag doesn't work - I am getting an error message `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8888/index.js"`

Comment: It should be working with the code I suggested. It clearly sets the `Content-Type` header to `/text/javascript`